# Bazel query find all test except from a particular folder

Tags: build, bazel

Bazel query command below queries all the tests in the current directory.

```
bazel query 'kind(".*_test", //...)'
```

However, I have a directory structure of the following type:

```
main_folder/
├── main_folder/ -> This will have main_folder_content1 folder as well
└── main_folder_content1/
    ├── BUILD
    ├── test1_test.cc
    └── test2_test.cc
```

Now when I run the above query test command, it is trying to include the main_folder(child) as well. My aim is to run the test on the contents of main_folder, but except on the child main_folder. I tried using - , --deleted_packages flag but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way, wherein, I can go inside parent main_folder folder and then list all the tests except for the child main_folder ?

I can do using a workaround i.e have main_folder child's path in .bazelignore of parent main_folder and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think `bazel query 'tests(//... - //main_folder/main_folder_content1/...)'` is what you're looking for. If you just want to run these tests, `bazel test //... - //main_folder/main_folder_content1/...` is more direct. If you just want the targets in `//main_folder` but not any subpackages, `//main_folder:all` will get those. All of these examples use [target patterns](https://bazel.build/run/build#specifying-build-targets), if you want to read about more variants.

[`tests`](https://bazel.build/query/language#tests) is a more accurate way to find things Bazel considers tests than `kind(".*_test")`.